# Why the recursive program does not show anything when I run it.

Tags: python, recursion, divide

```
def ispalindrome(s):
  """Assumes s is a str 
  returns true if s is a ispalindrome
  punctuation marks, blanks, and capitals are igored """
#s=raw_input("Please enter a word to check if it is a palindrome")
  def tochars(s):
   s=s.lower()
   letters=''
   for c in s :
     if c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
      letters=letters+c
   return letters

  def ispal(s):
   print ' ispalindrome called with' , s
   if len(s)<=1 :
    print "about to return to from base case"
    return True
   else :
      answer = s[0] == s[-1 ] and ispal (s[1:-1])
      print "about to return ",answer,"for" ,s
      return answer
   return ispal(tochars(s))



def testpal():
  print 'try doggod'
  print ispalindrome('doggod')
```

When I run the above code it is compiled seanlessly but returns nothing.There is no error message but the program prints nothing. Please give some suggstion.

Comment: ... if this is *the whole code* why do you expect anything to happen? You simply define several functions but never call any of them...

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
return ispal(tochars(s))
```

is indented too far.

This makes it part of the `ispal(s)` function, so it's never called.

Your indentation in general is very inconsistent (sometimes one, sometimes two, sometimes three spaces). If you don't fix that, you'll keep running into errors like this.

Also, you're never calling your `testpal()` function.

If you fix all these issues, it runs fine:

```
def ispalindrome(s):
  def tochars(s):
    s = s.lower()
    letters = ''
    for c in s:
      if c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        letters = letters + c
    return letters

  def ispal(s):
    print 'ispalindrome called with', s

    if len(s) <= 1:
      print "about to return to from base case"
      return True
    else:
      answer = s[0] == s[-1 ] and ispal (s[1:-1])
      print "about to return ", answer, "for", s
      return answer

  return ispal(tochars(s))

def testpal():
  print 'try doggod'
  print ispalindrome('doggod')

testpal()
```